# Specify Hadoop mapreduce input keys directly (not from a file)

Tags: hadoop

I'd like to generate some data using a mapreduce.  I'd like to invoke the job with one parameter N, and get Map called with each integer from 1 to N, once.

Obviously I want a `Mapper<IntWritable, NullWritable, <my output types>>`...that's easy.  But I can't figure out how to generate the input data!  Is there an `InputFormat` I'm not seeing somewhere that lets me just pull keys + values from a collection directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want each mapper to process all integers from 1 to N?  Or do you want to distribute the processing of integers 1 to N across the concurrently running mappers?

If the former, I believe you'll need to create a custom InputFormat.  If the latter, the easiest way might be to generate a text file with integers 1 to N, each integer on one line, and use LineInputFormat.

Comment: The latter; I thought of your solution, which should work, but it just seems so silly.  Why can't I do this programmatically?

Comment: You can do it programmatically with a custom InputFormat.  You will have to implement getSplits to return InputSplits that store ranges of values, and the RecordReader will return individual values over those ranges.  See http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html for more info.